# How to sort parsed content in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, rss

I've parsed rss-feeds from the different sources and I want to sort them by date. But sort function doesn't work good. It sorts the "newsdiv" blocks randomly. I don't understand why.
If I sort content witch is written directly into the html file, the function works well.

This is code:

```
function getRSS(feedUrl) {

$.get('proxy.php?url=' + feedUrl, function(data) {
    $(data).find('item').each(function() {

        var title = $(this).find('title').text();
        var url = $(this).find('link').text();
        var description = $(this).find('description').text();
        var pubDate = $(this).find('pubDate').text();

        var date = new Date(pubDate);
        var months = Array("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12");
        var string = date.getDate() + "-" + months[date.getMonth()] + "-" + date.getFullYear();

        var enc = $(this).find('enclosure');

        image_url = $(enc).attr('url');

        var html;
        html  = "<div class=\"newsdiv\"><div class=\"rsstitle\"><a href=\"" + url + "\" target=\"_blank\">"+title+"</a></div>";
        html += "<div class=\"rssdate\">" + string + "</div>";
        html += "<div class=\"rssdescription\">" + description + "<a href=\"" + url + "\" target=\"_blank\"> more</a></div>";
        html += "<img class=\"media\" src=\"" + image_url + "\" onerror=\"this.src='images/p.gif'\"></div>";

        $('#rssContent').append($(html));
    });
});
}

function getRSS1(feedUrl) {

$.get('proxy.php?url=' + feedUrl, function(data) {
    $(data).find('item').each(function() {

        var title = $(this).find('title').text();
        var url = $(this).find('link').text();
        var description = $(this).find('description').text();
        var pubDate = $(this).find('pubDate').text();

        var date = new Date(pubDate);
        var months = Array("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12");
        var string = date.getDate() + "-" + months[date.getMonth()] + "-" + date.getFullYear();

        var enc = $(this).find('enclosure');

        image_url = $(enc).attr('url');

        var html;
        html  = "<div class=\"newsdiv\"><div class=\"rsstitle\"><a href=\"" + url + "\" target=\"_blank\">"+title+"</a></div>";
        html += "<div class=\"rssdate\">" + string + "</div>";
        html += "<div class=\"rssdescription\">" + description + "<a href=\"" + url + "\" target=\"_blank\"> more</a></div>";
        html += "<img class=\"media\" src=\"" + image_url + "\" onerror=\"this.src='images/p.gif'\"></div>";

        $('#rssContent').append($(html));
    });
});
}

function getRSS2(feedUrl) {

$.get('proxy.php?url=' + feedUrl, function(data) {
    $(data).find('item').each(function() {

        var title = $(this).find('title').text();
        var url = $(this).find('link').text();
        var description = $(this).find('description').text();
        var pubDate = $(this).find('pubDate').text();

        var date = new Date(pubDate);
        var months = Array("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12");
        var string = date.getDate() + "-" + months[date.getMonth()] + "-" + date.getFullYear();

        var html;
        html  = "<div class=\"newsdiv\"><div class=\"rsstitle\"><a href=\"" + url + "\" target=\"_blank\">"+title+"</a></div>";
        html += "<div class=\"rssdate\">" + string + "</div>";
        html += "<div class=\"rssdescription\">" + description + "</div></div>";

        $('#rssContent').append($(html));
    });
});
}

$(document).ready(function() {
getRSS("http://source1.com");
getRSS1("http://source2.com");
getRSS2("http://source3.com");
});

function sortDescending(a, b) {
var date1 = $(a).find(".rssdate").text();
date1 = date1.split('-');
date1 = new Date(date1[2], date1[1] - 1, date1[0]);
var date2 = $(b).find(".rssdate").text();
date2 = date2.split('-');
date2 = new Date(date2[2], date2[1] - 1, date2[0]);

return date1 < date2;
};

function sortNews() {
$('#rssContent .newsdiv').sort(sortDescending).appendTo('#rssContent');
};
```

Comment: Check the value of date1 date2 - it may be they are not correct (new Date can be a pain in the cross browser butt in javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what's wrong.

```
return date2 - date1;
```